# Weird Threading with C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've encounter a weird problem with C# threading.

This is my sample program using thread to "activate" the Print() function at each agent in the agentList.

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        List<Agent> agentList = new List<Agent>();

        agentList.Add(new Agent("lion"));
        agentList.Add(new Agent("cat"));
        agentList.Add(new Agent("dog"));
        agentList.Add(new Agent("bird"));

        foreach (var agent in agentList) {
            new Thread(() => agent.Print()).Start();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Agent {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Agent(string name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void Print() {
        Console.WriteLine("Agent {0} is called", this.Name);
    }
}
```

And here is the result when I run the above program:

```
Agent cat is called
Agent dog is called
Agent bird is called
Agent bird is called
```

But what I expected is something contains all 4 agents like

```
Agent lion is called
Agent cat is called
Agent dog is called
Agent bird is called
```

The most amazing thing is that if I called the threads outside the foreach, it works!

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<Agent> agentList = new List<Agent>();

        agentList.Add(new Agent("leecom"));
        agentList.Add(new Agent("huanlv"));
        agentList.Add(new Agent("peter"));
        agentList.Add(new Agent("steve"));

        new Thread(() => agentList[0].Print()).Start();
        new Thread(() => agentList[1].Print()).Start();
        new Thread(() => agentList[2].Print()).Start();
        new Thread(() => agentList[3].Print()).Start();


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The result of the above code is exactly what I expected. So what's the problem here?

Comment: That's what happens when you close over the loop variable: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: @dlev, You should post that an an answer so he can marked it solved.  Your answer is correct.

Comment: You know, if you're using .Net 4.0 you can use Parallel for each loop to do what you're wanting. I would think that would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have there is a closure. You're closing on a variable inside a foreach loop. What is happening is that the variable is getting overwritten before your thread starts so you have two iterations with the same value.

The easy fix is to capture the value inside the foreach loop before using it:

```
foreach(var a in agentList)
{
    var agent = a;
    new Thread(() => agent.Print()).Start();
}
```

Comment: Notice that Jetbrains' Resharper would have notified you of such issue. (I am not affiliated with Jetbrains in an shape or form... just love Resharper!)

Answer (score 2):

You are capturing `agent` in a closure, which can be problematic with multi-threading.  Assign to a local variable first:

```
    foreach (var agent in agentList) {
        var temp = agent;
        new Thread(() => temp.Print()).Start();
    }
```

Comment: temp and agent will have same refrence . so there will be chance of same wrong output.will work for primitive datatpye not on custom ones.

Comment: @user998660 - temp is scoped inside the foreach and will only ever have the original reference even after agent is changed on the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Justin: Yep, correct.  It's the local reference that's needed to keep the reference itself from changing in the closure.

Answer (score 1):

Change your foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (var agent in agentList) 
{
    var agent1 = agent;
    new Thread(() => agent1.Print()).Start();         
}
```

copying the value to a local variable (which looks a little stupid) avoids the thread of using a variable that might change when it comes to run.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of var agent which could have same refrence with in threads.
That's why your eariler approach is not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Without using some kind of thread sync (like a ManualResetEvent), you cannot guarantee the order that threads will be processed. If you want to perform multiple steps in order, I would suggest you bundle the work up, then perform all of it in a single background thread.

I like the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) object:

```
List<Agent> agentList = new List<Agent>();

agentList.Add(new Agent("leecom"));
agentList.Add(new Agent("huanlv"));
agentList.Add(new Agent("peter"));
agentList.Add(new Agent("steve"));

BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
{
    foreach (var item in agentList)
    {
        item.Print();
    }
};

worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Oh yeah, other answers are correct, it's a closure. I'd still use my code, but that's my flavor. :D

Comment: Your code is fundamentally different. It will only use a single background worker whereas the OP wants a separate worker for each Agent. You would still need the fix for the closure in your code.

Comment: The OP never explicitly stated that they wanted each print called in individual threads. Many times developers create individual threads, when a single thread will do. Also, because the loop is happening inside of the new thread, variable closure isn't an issue in the same way as the original code sample, provided they don't modify agentList after calling RunWorkingAsync, my code sample will work correctly.